# Magical array A of N integers with K length

Tags: arrays, algorithm, number-theory

Given **an array A of N integers**, An array called magical if its all the elements have exactly **3 divisors**. Now you have to convert the given array into the magical **array of K length**. You can perform the following operations in any order of time.

1. Increase the value of any element of the array by 1.
2. Decrease the value of any element of the array by 1.
3. Delete any element of the array.

Constraints:

```
1 <= N <= 1000000
1 <= K <= N
1 <= A <= 1000000

Sample Input
5(size of the array) 3(K)
1 4 10 8 15

Output
4
```

A solution I tried:

Iterated every element of the array, checking near a prime number square and adding this difference to global count operation(variable used to count required operations). This time-order is n^2.

Searching for a better solution.

Comment: What are you trying to minimize ? The number of operations or the computation time of the algorithm ?

Comment: Computation time less than the order of n^2, searching for a better solution which clear every edge case. As for now, my solution didn't clear edge cases and I don't know exact edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array with absolute values of differences with closest prime squares

Use [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm to separate `K` smaller differences (average complexity tends to `O(N)`, while the worst quadratic case is possible)

Calculate their sum

Answer (score 0):

you can try with below method to find number with 3 divisors

```
void numbersWith3Divisors(int n) 
{ 
    boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[n+1]; 
    Arrays.fill(isPrime, true); 
    isPrime[0] = isPrime[1] = false; 

    for (int p=2; p*p<=n; p++) 
    { 
       if (isPrime[p] == true) 
        { 
            for (int i=p*2; i<=n; i += p) 
                isPrime[i] = false; 
        } 
    } 

    System.out.print("Numbers with 3 divisors :- "); 
    for (int i=0;  i*i <= n ; i++) 
        if (isPrime[i]) 
            System.out.print(i*i + " "); 
}
```

the same you can apply for array,

hope it will help

Comment: Read the whole question once it is not finding prime square.

Comment: please test my code its not about finding prime numbers, it will  give the divisor for given number

Comment: Yeah, it is correct in finding prime square/3 divisor of a number. But you need to make an array of length N to K. where each element in K-size array should have exactly 3 divisors.

Comment: I believe using above method we can iterate array and do the same